ORA-03113: end-of-file on communication channel - SQL Plus - Oracle Express Edition
SQL*Plus: Release 18.0.0.0.0 - Production on Wed Nov 13 09:30:39 2024
Version 18.4.0.0.0
Copyright (c) 1982, 2018, Oracle.  All rights reserved.
Enter user-name: sys as sysdba
Enter password:
ERROR:
ORA-03113: end-of-file on communication channel
Process ID: 0
Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0

Do you intend to ask a question? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

The error ORA-03113 is a "Generic Error" because it can be many causes. But try restart your database and connect again please.
And share your alert log... Tks!
